# How to localize app name in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to localize app name in bare React Native app project? I updated app name in `strings.xml` at `android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and `<string name="app_name">New App Name</string>`.

Likewise, in iOS I changed display name in Xcode and updated `CFBundleDisplayName` value in `info.plist`, but how do I localize app name based on selected device language and is it possible to localize app name from Redux store?

Thank you in advance

Comment: online lot of resource available for localize app name android and ios.

Comment: Mostly lack details and from 4 5 years ago and no reference of localization getting from Redux store, would you mind share some links?

Answer (score 0):

This article contains a thorough explanation of how this works for ios: https://hackernoon.com/localize-an-application-name-in-react-native-c36c4b2be7c3

As for Android, it's just about creating a file under android/app/src/main/res/ copy the file under values/strings.xml put it under ur language-region specification ex. values-en-rUS/strings.xml and then change the app name in there